# Converting strange SQL Server JOIN syntax to MySQL syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a SQL Server query that I am attempting to port to MySQL, but the JOIN syntax is something that I have never seen used before. The query is from a view designed to measure procedure code usage. What the heck is going on with the JOIN syntax just past T.PatID = P.ID, and the third LEFT OUTER JOIN, and what equivalent syntax can we use in MySQL? It does not like this JOIN syntax at all (disregard the ISNULL and CONVERT SQL Server specific syntax)

```
SELECT
                T.Code
              , P.LastName
              , P.FirstName
              , T.TranDate
              , CD.DaysUnits
              , T.TranAmt
              , TD.FullName AS Provider
              , ISNULL(TD.ID, ISNULL(AD.ID, PD.ID))                   AS DoctorID
FROM
                dbo.Doctors AS PD
                INNER JOIN
                                dbo.Transactions AS T
                INNER JOIN
                                dbo.Patients AS P
                                ON
                                                T.PatID = P.ID
                                                ON
                                                                PD.ID = P.DoctorID
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                dbo.Doctors AS TD
                                                ON
                                                                T.DoctorID = TD.ID
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                dbo.Doctors AS AD
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                dbo.Appointments
                                                ON
                                                                AD.ID                                                           = dbo.Appointments.DoctorID
                                                                AND CONVERT(varchar(20), dbo.Appointments.ScheduleDateTime, 8) <> '00:00:00'
                                                                ON
                                                                                T.ApptID = dbo.Appointments.ID
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                dbo.ChargeDetails AS CD
                                                                ON
                                                                                T.ID = CD.ChargeTranID
                                WHERE
                                                (
                                                                T.Code IS NOT NULL
                                                )
```

The SHOW CREATE TABLE are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Doctors
             (

                          ID       int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
                        , FullName varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL

             )


CREATE TABLE Patients
             (
                          LName                     varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
                        , FName                     varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL 
                        , ID                        int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY

             )

CREATE TABLE Transactions
             (
                           TranType           varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  Code               varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  TranSubType        varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  Description         varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  TranDate           datetime
                        ,  PatID              int(10) DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  ID                 int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
                        ,  TranAmt            decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  ApptID             int(10) DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  DoctorID          int(10) DEFAULT NULL

             )


CREATE TABLE ChargeDetails
             (

                           DaysUnits          varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
                        -- DaysUnits is just an int ranging from 1 to 2
                        ,  ChargeTranID       int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
             )

CREATE TABLE Appointments
             (

                           DoctorID              int(10) DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  PatientID            int(10) DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  ScheduleDateTime      datetime DEFAULT NULL
                        ,  ID                   int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
             )
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have some syntax error in your query. Transactions.Code does not exists and used in the where clause... in your table definition. there is extra comma ',' at the beginning of the CREATE TABLE ChargeDetails and CREATE TABLE Appointments... the first join has no condition: dbo.Doctors AS PD INNER JOIN dbo.Transactions AS T (missing ON)...  you need to fix these errors before converting it to MySQL.

Comment: Where did you get this query from? It is invalid tsql that cannot possibly work in SQL Server at least in none of the versions I have seen. I initially thought that maybe there was something simple like a missing join or a typo but as @Sarhang pointed out there are too many errors there.

Comment: If I was you I would junk this code and start from scratch.

Comment: @Sarhang, Alex That is completely valid syntax for sql server. Not typical, but completely valid. Just a plain inner join where logically the join between P and T occurs before PD and P. But such constructs are needed when you start the from clause with a secondary table. It would make far more sense to have specified Transactions as the first table in the from clause.

Comment: @3C41DC If you do not understand what the query does and how it works in sql server, you cannot possibly migrate it. Given the basic schema / naming errors you introduced, you should get some help.

Comment: @zarruq, alex I've attempted to find similar questions on StackOverflow dealing with this kind of join as it relates to MySQL; however, I have not been able to find anything as it is.This is a trimmed-down query of a view that a software program uses; it does work and is syntatically valid in SQL Server, but invalid in MySQL.

Comment: @SMor: On the join between PD.DoctorID and P.DoctorID are you saying that it is equivalent to INNER JOIN Patients ON PD.DoctorID and P.DoctorID?

Comment: I don't think your query is syntactically correct. However if by some miracle it works, then replace `ISNULL` with `CASE` and `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), dbo.Appointments.ScheduleDateTime, 8)` with `CONVERT(dbo.Appointments.ScheduleDateTime, CHAR)`

Comment: @3C41DC yes. And I'll guess that if you migrate the tables correctly as is, that query will at least execute in MySQL (except for that strange convert crap - which you will need to investigate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar (and simplified) query using the same structure as the first query. The second query moves the joins around to make things easier to read.

```
set nocount on; 
use tempdb;
go

declare @doc table (id int not null); 
declare @tran table (id int not null, patid int not null); 
declare @patients table (id int not null, docid int not null);

insert @doc (id) values (1);
insert @patients (id, docid) values (25, 1);
insert @tran (id, patid) values (100, 25)

select * 
from @doc as pd 
inner join @tran as t
inner join @patients as p 
on t.patid = p.id
on pd.id = p.docid;

select * 
from @tran as t 
inner join @patients as p 
on t.patid = p.id
inner join @doc as pd 
on pd.id = p.docid;
```

Other things look strange. I don't see a need to join to appointments but I'm not going to spend a lot of time to figure out the logic and the schema. The convert usage seems like a bad way to check for null - unless there is a special "flag" datetime value that is used as the equivalent to null. Again, you need to understand the query, the goal of the query, the schema on which it is based, and how the tables are populated. Quite frankly, this code raises concerns about the quality of the entire system.
.

Comment: I agree, rather than try to figure out what the heck the original query writers were thinking, it's wiser to try your approach. Thanks for your help!